# Sequelize.js - how to properly use get methods from associations (no sql query on each call)?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.js for ORM and have a few associations (which actually doesn't matter now). My models get `get` and `set` methods from those associations. Like this (from docs):

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {/* ... */})
var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {/* ... */})

// One-way associations
Project.hasOne(User)

/*
...
Furthermore, Project.prototype will gain the methods getUser and setUser
according to the first parameter passed to define.
*/
```

So now, I have `Project.getUser()`, which returns a Promise. But if I call this twice on the very same object, I get SQL query executed twice.

My question is - am I missing something out, or this is an expected behavior? I actually don't want to make additional queries each time I call the same method on this object.

If this is expected - should I use custom getters with member variables which I manually populate and return if present? Or there is something more clever? :)

**Update**
As from DeBuGGeR's answer - I understand I can use `includes` when making a query in order to eager load everything, but I simply don't need it, and I can't do it all the time. It's waste of resources and a big overhead if I load my entire DB at the beginning, just to understand (by some criteria) that I won't need it. I want to make additional queries depending on situation. But I also can't afford to destroy all models (DAO objects) that I have and create new ones, with all the info inside them. I should be able to update parts of them, which are missing (from relations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of things is clear - **every** call to `get[Association]` (for example `Project.getUser()`) **WILL** result in database query.

Sequelize does not maintain any kind of state nor cache for the results. You can get `user` in the Promisified result of the call, but if you want it again - you will have to make another query.

What @DeBuGGeR said - about using accessors is also not true - accessors are present only **immediately after** a query, and are not preserved.

As sometimes this is not ok, you have to implement some kind of caching system by yourself. Here comes the tricky part:

**IF** you want to use the same get method `Project.getUser()`, you won't be able to do it, as Sequelize overrides your `instanceMethods`. For example, if you have the association mentioned above, this **won't work**:

```
instanceMethods: {
    getUser: function() {
        // check if you have it, otherwise make a query
    }
}
```

There are few possible ways to fix it - either change Sequelize core a little (to first check if the method exists), or use some kind of wrapper to those functions.

More details about this can be found here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3707

Thanks to [mickhansen](https://github.com/mickhansen) for the cooperation on how to understand what to do :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use getUser() it will make the query call, it dosent give you access to the user. You can manually save it to project.user or project.users depending on the association.

But you can try Eager Loading

```
Project.find({
  include: [
    { model: User, as: 'user' } // here you HAVE to specify the same alias as you did in your association
  ]
}).success(function(project){
project.user // contains the user

});
```

Also e.g of getUser(). Dont expect it to automatically cache user and dont override this cleverly as it will create side effects. getUser is expected to get from database and it should!

```
Project.getUser().then(function(user){
   // user is available and is a sequelize object
   project.user = user; // save project.user and use it till u want to
})
```

Comment: Don't understand your second part. I clearly want to use the ORM the way it should be used - to work with models directly. I get the project, then start using it from different places (files). In many of them I want to check if there is user. And because I have associations, I end up using `getUser`. But I don't want it to query the database each time, of course! I don't understand WHY it should be from database, every single time? :) If I have to wrap orm models in order to save state variables - then this is not truly ORM :)

Comment: The correct way to access it is "project.user". getUser is wrapper to sql query. Do you want a cache in between? if(!project.user) return project.getUser(); Could serve as one!

Comment: And sequelize is an awesome ORM :) Definitely the one to make your life much easier. Just dont mix accessor and query methods.

Comment: Well, uhm, if we go to the previous example, this is **not** working: `Project.getUser().then(function(){ Project.User; // undefined }`; edit - and don't get me wrong on Sequelize - I just need to know how it's actually working (and I hope it does as it should be)

Comment: Well I have to call this piece of code at least once, just to be sure that it's already updated from DB. And where do I call this? In my custom instance method I guess.. :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Short version: Things change. If you want to `get` the current `User`, `getUser()`. If you want to save that user so you operate on the same one repeatedly... do that.